# Power Query change values in a cell on condition

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table with 100+ equipment. The sample is below:

| Equipment | Rounded Start of operation | Rounded end of operation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| eq1 | 01/09/2020 20:10 | 01/09/2020 20:15 |
| eq1 | 01/09/2020 20:15 | 01/09/2020 20:40 |
| eq2 | 01/09/2020 20:30 | 01/09/2020 20:45 |
| eq2 | 01/09/2020 20:50 | 01/09/2020 21:55 |

As you can see the start of the second operation is the same as the end of the first operation for eq1.

I need to increase such start of the operation on 5 minutes.

I have tried to add 2 additional columns:

- column_1 = equipment+rounded start of operation
- column_2 = equipment+rounded end of operation.

Then I wanted to check if column_2 contains a value of column_1 but could not find any good way to do it. Table.Contains took around an hour to calculate everything.

Is there a better way to do it in Power Query?

Comment: What if, like the first row, moving the start forward by 5 minutes made start >= end?

Comment: That is ok if start and end will be the same.